# Can we program in Solidity the distributed computations ?

Tags: solidity, contract-development

Can we use the **solidity** language (or any other language) to develop a program that each node of the network does the same operation with different inputs and that the nodes can communicate between them ?

For example, we have 3 nodes in the network, can we develop a program as following : The first node N1 computes C1=**m**+r1 (where **m** is initiated input for the node N1, r1 is randomly generated by the node N1) then sends the result to the next node. This second node N2 will compute C2=C1+r2 (where r2 is randomly generated by the node N2) then send the result C2 to the last node N3. This latter will finally compute C3=C2+r3.

Thanks for help !

Comment: to clarify your question, are these 3 nodes calling the same function in the smart contract passing in different inputs? If they are, then the end state of the variables will be different, depending on which node calls the function first.

Comment: Yes. Each node will have a function called `wait()` that waits for a message from another node, and a function called `send()` that will send the result computed to another node.

Comment: what is the purpose of doing this? This is definitely doable has I have done something similar. However, all 3 nodes will have the same variable state by the end of the execution -- shared ledger.

Comment: Given the structure of the network doing something in a node is the same as doing it in any node in terms of operations, there is no particular advantage of one operation running in node A and the next in Node B (whihc actually is what happen always), because node A and B have the same virtual machine and the same data at a particular time point, the data doesn't change with location but with time.